# regex, last occurrence and cURL options

Tags: regex

**The Requirement**

Find all occurences of...

```
curl_setopt($this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

...and extract the 3rd parameter ($url in the above example)

**Solution (partial)**

```
curl_setopt\(.*?CURLOPT_URL.*?,(.*?)\)
```

It returns desired results...

```
array(
 0  =>  array( 0    =>  curl_setopt($this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url) )
 1  =>  array( 0    =>   $url )
)
```

... but only when each **curl_setopt** occurrence is in a separate line. E.g.

```
curl_setopt($this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_FILE, $fileHandle);
curl_setopt($this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

**The Problem**

The single line version of the same code code is not parsed properly.

```
curl_setopt($this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); curl_setopt($this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_FILE, $fileHandle); curl_setopt($this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

I think the last instance of a word will somehow have to be incorporated in the expression, specifically the below concept, but I cannot get it to work.

```
abc(?!.*abc)
```

Comment: I'd think of [`[^)]*?` instead of `.*?`](https://regex101.com/r/ei7RMK/1) but not sure if understand right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you use `CURLOPT_URL` but in the longer version there is also `CURLOPT_HEADER` and `CURLOPT_FILE` so the match would not stop there but match until `CURLOPT_URL` which is at the end so you get a longer match.

You might update your pattern to:

```
curl_setopt\(.*?CURLOPT_.*?,(.*?)\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pEIQPs/1)

Or you could use a negated character class to match not a comma or a newline if the match should be on the same line:

```
curl_setopt\([^\n,]+,\h*CURLOPT_\S+,\h*([^,\n]+)\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j1vwLd/1)

Comment: The first option returns all three options. I can then identify CURLOPT_URL in the output. It gives me what I need, thank you.